# Impact stat says I have reached a thousand thousand people

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, people-reached

The new *Impact* stat on the profile pages switches to displaying the number `1.0m` when you reach a million. But it only does so at `1,001,000`. When you actually hit one million it displays the rather odd `1000k`:

[image]

This is obviously a real blocker and has to be fixed immediately.

Comment: I was gonna ask the same thing as well.. http://i.stack.imgur.com/YJKrJ.png

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should be fixed as of the latest build.

Comment: Did you alter the reputation rounding for 100k+ users in their usercards too? Hover over CMS's reputation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457299/local-javascript-scoping-issue/11457447#11457447) for example; his rep is over 365.5k but it is rounded *down* to 365k.

Comment: Yeaaaah, sort of by design... But I don't particularly like it.  Will dig in yet more tomorrow, i18n is just a pain around numbers in general.

Comment: @MartijnPieters should be properly rounding to nearest now, not just flooring it.

Comment: @KevinMontrose: \o/